# BackPress - which libraries i need to load to work with Multisite?

Tags: multisite

i have successfully install and run those projects based on BackPress.

1. SupportPress: https://supportpress.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/
2. GeoPress: http://geopress.my/

I try to understand how i can build some custom projects that will need the MultiSite feature with the subdomains option.

Does anyone knows how to do this?
Which libraries i have to load?

thanks a lot!

Comment: BackPress does not have multisite support, you'll have to code that in yourself.

Comment: @Soulseekah Should be an answer instead :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BackPress does not offer any multisite support libraries, you'll have to build those yourself with the support of the WordPress multisite source code.

The following are the major parts making up multisite functionality:

- http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-admin/network.php, deployment of a multisite environment.
- http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-admin/includes/ms.php, most multisite administration functionality
- http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-admin/includes/ms-deprecated.php, deprecated administration functionality, can have some useful stuff
- http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/ms-functions.php, Multiite API (http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/ms-deprecated.php deprecated)
- http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/ms-load.php, shows how a multisite is loaded
- http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/ms-settings.php contains important bootup routines
- http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-load.php general WordPress bootup

As you can imagine, it's going to be quite hard to bring it all together, but everything is pretty much there, with additional bits and pieces scattered across other files. By the way, the old MU project http://mu.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk is also inside of a WordPress environment, so it doesn't give any advantage; you'll still have to gather the functionality together piece by piece.

Unless you have a very good reason to use BackPress, I'd stick with WordPress instead, a lot can be done with [must-use plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) in terms of providing a standalone application package.

Hope this helps.